# Is there a way to force bundler to accept a particular version of a gem?

Tags: ruby, bundler

I have a rails project where certain third party dependencies insist on a certain version of another third party library (using ~> ) When I try to do a bundle install, I get the following:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "faraday":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    faraday (= 0.9.2)

  In Gemfile:
    linkedin-v2 (>= 0.1.7) was resolved to 0.1.7, which depends on
      faraday (~> 0.11)

    twitter (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.17.0, which depends on
      faraday (~> 0.9.0)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

Applicable segments from the Gemfile:

```
...
gem 'linkedin-v2', '>= 0.1.7'
...
gem 'twitter', '~> 5.0'
...
```

In this case, I am almost certain that there is no incompatibility in the third party library, and after testing I could use faraday 0.11 without issue. Is there a directive I can use in the Gemfile way to tell bundler just to accept a certain version of a gem, perhaps while printing out a warning?

I can fork the third party project on github (In this case the 'twitter' project) and then change the version number of faraday in its Gemfile, and then reference this forked project in my Gemfile - but this seems like a really ugly and overly complex hack. (i.e: It introduces the issue of keeping the forked project up to date.)

Comment: The bundler generally knows what it's doing when it comes to identifying dependencies. Are you saying that you're almost certain that you know better than the bundler? You can force a version, such as `gem 'twitter', '5.0'` but then if this causes a dependency conflict the `bundler` will have no choice but to end with an error. If your desire was to stick to a certain set of known, successfully interdependent versions, then those would get locked in by using the same `Gemfile.lock` file.

Comment: @lurker - What I'm saying is that twitter 5.0 insists on using faraday 0.9.0 . linkedin-v2 insists on using faraday 0.11.0 . If I fork twitter 5.0 on github, and change the Gemfile so that it specifies faraday 0.11.0 , and then point my project's Gemfile at this forked version, all my specs pass, and functionally my project seems to work. I was wondering if there is a way to get this behavior without having to create forks of the projects on which mine depends - which feels like an ugly hack to me.

Comment: I would argue that the non-ugly hack would be to create a fork, fix the dependency and that create a PR against the original gem. Doing so would probably help others too.